# Fresh SSD - High Power On Count when putting hibernate mode (Win8.1)

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, ssd, battery, hibernate

I've just bought a brand new Samsung SSD Evo 840 and I found that when hibernating, it increases Power On Count too much (in 1.5 months) as:
[image]

As you can see Power On Count increases as crazy when hibernate, also drains my battery life and I can feel it gets hot in hibernating.

Is is normal and we shouldn't use Hibernate when using SSD on laptop right?

Let's me know if you get same problem with me.
Thanks

Comment: Why hibernate with and SSD? The start up speed from cold boot is faster than traditional platters. Plus you are performing a bunch of unneeded writes to the drive in hibernate. Put it to sleep or shut it down...would be better.

Comment: @CarlB I open a lot of tabs in Chrome or Visual Studio and I'm a lazy guy hehe. That's great to found that, luckily it's just 1.5 months :)